# Why is Vims html indentation slow and doesn't indent all my html tags? 

Tags: html, xml, vim

When I try to set the filetype to xml it works really well and is quiet fast too. Is there a way of indenting html just like xml without changing the filetype?

Answer (score 0):

Strange. I've never had such a problem. Anyway, if you want you can set all filetypes detected to be HTML to use XML instead by adding the line below to `~/.vimrc`.

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *     if &ft == 'html' | set ft=xml | endif
```

Comment: the problem here is, that i need it to be set as html in order to use some plugins i have installed.

Comment: What do you mean when you say indentation is slow? Have you tried disabling some plugins to see if one of those is the problem? That seems likely to be the case.